# DynamoDb table design: Single table or multiple tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, nosql

I’m quite new to NoSQL and DynamoDB and I used to RDBMS. I’m designing database for a game and we're using DynamoDB and AWS Lambda for our backend. I created a table name “Users” for player profile that contains the user information and resources. Because the game has inventory system I also created a table name “UserItems”.

It’s all good until I realized DynamoDB don’t have transaction and any operation that is executed on both table (for example using an item that increase resource) has a chance of failure on one table while success on other and will cause missing data which affect our customers.

So I was thinking maybe my multiple tables design is not good since it’s a habit of me to design multiple table when I’m working with RDBMS. Which let me to think of storing the entire “UserItems” as hash in “Users” but I’m not sure this is a good practice because the size of a single row in Users table will be really big (we may have 500 unique items per users) and each time I pull or put data from/to “Users” (most of the time don’t need “UserItems” data) the read/write throughput will be also really large.

What should I do, keep the multiple tables design and handle transaction manually or switch to single table design? Or maybe there is a 3rd option?

**Updated: more information about my use case**

Currently I have 2 tables

- Users: UserId (key), Username, Gold
- UserItems: UserId (partition key), ItemId (sort key), Name, GoldValue

Scenarios:

1. User buy an item: Users.Gold will be deduced, new UserItem will be add to UserItems table.
2. User sell an item: Users.Gold will be increased, the Item will be deleted from UserItems table.

In both scenarios above I will have to do 2 update operation for 2 tables which without transaction there is a chance one of them failed.

To solve that I consider using single table solution which is a single Users table with 4 columns UserId(key), Username, Gold, UserItems. However there are two things I'm worried about:

1. Data in UserItems might be come to big for a single cell because one user could have up to 500 items.
2. To add/delete item I have to pull the UserItems from dynamodb, add/delete item and then put it back into Users. So I have to do 1 read and 1 write operation for 1 action. And because of issue (1) the read/write data size could become really big.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NoSql database is best suited for non-trasactional data. If you bring normalization(splitting your data into multiple tables) into noSQL, then you are beating the whole purpose of it. If performance is what matters most, then you should consider only having a single table for your use case. DynamoDB supports Range Keys, and also supports Secondary Indices. For your usecase, it would be better to redesign your table to use Range Keys.
If you can share more details about your current table, maybe i can help you with more inputs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It seems single table is the solution for my use case. Still I'm worry about the size of data inside a single row and the read/write process when I'm storing everything in a single table. I've updated my question. I hope it helps you understand my situation.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/performing-conditional-writes-using-the-amazon-dynamodb-transaction-library/

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using NodeJs for Lambda and there is no transaction library for JS yet.

Comment: Where is the doc about Range Keys @letmesolve??

Comment: "_NoSql database is best suited for non-trasactional data_". I have to disagree with this one. NoSQL simply means non-relational databases which describes variety of systems. We can roughly class them as key-value stores(as in DynamoDB), document databases(e.g MongoDB) and graph databases(e.g Neo4j). What distinguishes a system to be adequate for non-transactional workloads is it's underlying storage strategy(row oriented vs column oriented) while column oriented systems are more suitable for OLAP(non-transactional) workloads. For example Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 22):

FWIW, the AWS documentation on [NoSQL Design for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html) suggests to use a single table:

> As a general rule, you should maintain as few tables as possible in a
>   DynamoDB application. As emphasized earlier, most well designed
>   applications require **only one table**, unless there is a specific reason
>   for using multiple tables.
>
> Exceptions are cases where high-volume time series data are involved,
>   or datasets that have very different access patterns—but these are
>   exceptions. A single table with inverted indexes can usually enable
>   simple queries to create and retrieve the complex hierarchical data
>   structures required by your application.

Comment: The curious thing to me...they say most applications require only one table but one of their two use cases uses three tables https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.CreateTables.html#SampleData.CreateTables2

Comment: Good point @MichaelBrown. Just following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) and they seem to use one table per entity without discrimination. Makes it hard to decide. However, this is all good insight from everyone.

Comment: @MichaelBrown i think that is just for simplicity's sake - it's a tutorial for absolute beginners so wise not to bog the reader down with advanced concepts to begin with

Comment: I've actually taken an advanced class on noSQL design and the whole "single table" rule is not even a good rule.

Comment: Less tables in DynamoDB is better

Comment: @alambertt Is there any actual performance or cost benefit to keeping these two entities(Users, UserItems) in the same table? From what I understand, the cost should not have a difference right?

Comment: It is about joins. If there is an access pattern which would require a join (think a webpage with a list of items), then the absolute fastest way to get this data is to either have the table in a format with the data all aligned naturally for the list, or make a GSI that takes care of that case.
But the trick is, GSI's cannot be accross tables. This is why Single Table deisgn is needed, or may eventually be needed should you access patterns increase/change